# How to use launch4j in Eclipse to run the application and develop it?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, launch4j

We are developing an application using musicg library, when we run the program in eclipse getting outofmemory exception.

Below is the class

```
public class FingerprintDemo{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String filename = "Fun - Some Nights (ORIGINAL.wav";

        // create a wave object
        Wave wave = new Wave("D:\\DropBox\\Dropbox\\Convencion 2012\\AUDIOS WAV/"+filename);

        // get the fingerprint
        byte[] fingerprint=wave.getFingerprint();

        // dump the fingerprint
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager=new FingerprintManager();
        fingerprintManager.saveFingerprintAsFile(fingerprint, "out/"+filename+".fingerprint");

        // load fingerprint from file
        byte[] loadedFp=fingerprintManager.getFingerprintFromFile("out/"+filename+".fingerprint");

        /*
        // fingerprint bytes checking
        for (int i=0; i<fingerprint.length; i++){
            System.out.println(fingerprint[i]+" vs "+loadedFp[i]);
        }
        */
    }
}
```

When I run this program it give below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.musicg.wave.extension.Spectrogram.buildSpectrogram(Spectrogram.java:117)
    at com.musicg.wave.extension.Spectrogram.<init>(Spectrogram.java:76)
    at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getSpectrogram(Wave.java:237)
    at com.musicg.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.extractFingerprint(FingerprintManager.java:83)
    at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprint(Wave.java:329)
    at com.musicg.main.demo.FingerprintDemo.main(FingerprintDemo.java:31)
```

I did the jar of the class and configured it in Launch4j and executed, it's working fine with out exception.

```
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>D:\musicg\musicg.jar</jar>
  <outfile>D\musicg\\\musicg\.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle>MusicG</errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <customProcName>true</customProcName>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <jre>
    <path>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\</path>
    <minVersion>1.4.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <initialHeapSize>512</initialHeapSize>
    <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

How to get rid of this exception or how to configure launch4j in Eclipse and call the program to execute?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an OutOfMemoryError in Eclipse because you have not increased the maximum heap size in your Run Configuration.  In your Launch4J script however, you did increase it: `<maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>`

To fix the issue in Eclipse, open the [Run Configurations dialog](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm).  Switch to the Arguments tab and enter your Xmx (max heap size) argument.

[image]

It's really not appropriate to run your Launch4J script from Eclipse, use the Run Configurations for that.  Although you can create say an Ant script that will run Launch4J and build your .exe.